# Doctrine onDelete Foreign key constraints

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations

**Quick sketch**
I want to delete a parent entity without removing it's children, instead set the referenced column to NULL

**My programming**
I added `onDelete="SET NULL"` to the joinColumn of my child entity like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Backend\Modules\Ads\Domain\Ad\Ad", inversedBy="rewarded")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ad_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $ad;
```

This is the parent entity association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Backend\Modules\Ads\Domain\Rewarded\Rewarded", mappedBy="ad")
 */
private $rewarded;
```

**The problem**
On delete of the parent it throws me this error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
```

I already tried adding `"remove", "persist"` without much success. Using persist it will still cause the error and with remove enabled it will just remove the row.

I have found none working solution for this so far, thanks already!

Comment: Have you run schema update command ?

Comment: Yes I did, the relation exists with On Delete = SET NULL within the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. My entity I wanted to set NULL was dependent on another entity which was depending on the one I'm removing also. The method I used above is fully working when implemented everywhere where needed.

Thanks.